# Travis is not setting the cran repo

Tags: r, travis-ci

The travis-ci build always errors out at this point right after curl finishes downloading the R source tarball and setting `$R_LIBS_USER` variable.

the instructions are found here: 
https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-build/blob/master/lib/travis/build/script/r.rb#L108

```
$ curl -Lo /tmp/R-3.3.2-$(lsb_release -cs).xz https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-travis/R-3.3.2-$(lsb_release -cs).xz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 39.3M  100 39.3M    0     0  92.3M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 92.9M

$ tar xJf /tmp/R-3.3.2-$(lsb_release -cs).xz -C ~

$ rm /tmp/R-3.3.2-$(lsb_release -cs).xz
$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/R/site-library $R_LIBS_USER

$ sudo chmod 2777 /usr/local/lib/R /usr/local/lib/R/site-library $R_LIBS_USER

$ Rscript -e 'update.packages(ask = FALSE)'
Error in contrib.url(repos, type) : 
  trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
Calls: update.packages -> available.packages -> contrib.url
Execution halted
```

This is the link to my full build report:
https://travis-ci.org/etheleon/MetamapsDB

From the error, `trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror` it seems like the cran mirror is not set. However reading the docs from Travis-CI, https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/r#Environment-Variables, it is specified in `.Rprofile.site` where the `$R_PROFILE` variable is set

`R_PROFILE=~/.Rprofile.site`

In my travis.yml I've specified cran repo to `cran: https://cloud.r-project.org`

Separately, I noticed in successful build logs for other R packages like [ggplot2](https://travis-ci.org/tidyverse/ggplot2)

The following line (below) is executed right where I get the error message but it doesn't show up in my build logs

```
echo 'options(repos = c(CRAN = "https://cloud.r-project.org"))' > ~/.Rprofile.site
```

below is my travis.yml for reference

```
language: R
cache: packages
sudo: false

r_github_packages:
  - etheleon/sigma

cran: https://cloud.r-project.org
```

Comment: also reported by others 
https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-build/commit/440138117cffa94bd9a093756739000b43110c7d